# Django class based view URL API

Tags: python, api, django

I kind of started making an API for my site in a Django class based view because it seemed logical and now it has gotten quite large and unruly and I am starting to wonder if I am doing this correctly.

```
class URLAPI(View):

    def get(self, request):

         if request.GET.get('param') == "foo":
             ...

         elif request.GET.get('param') == "bar":
             ...

         elif request.GET.get('param') == "foo" and request.GET.get('param2') == "arg":
             ...
```

I did the same thing with the post function creating conditionals for the data that is coming in. What do you think about this?

Comment: Huge recommendation: use an existing framework like Django REST framework instead of rolling your own. You'll save a lot of time down the road, because you won't have to handle all of the special casing that's required. (Disclaimer: I'm a maintainer of DRF, but if there is a better API framework that suits your needs, my comment also applies to it)

Comment: I've been meaning to look into that, I had this one nearly complete by the time I realized that did what I needed. Will definitely check it out in the future

Answer (score 3):

If you are going to have a lot of cases, and each one is quite complex (more than a few lines) I would ditch the `if/elif` approach.

Instead I would have inner functions, one for each case. Then a dictionary will map each case (`'foo'`, `'bar'` etc) to its function.

For example:

```
class URLAPI(View):
    def get(self, request):
        def act_on_foo():
            ...
        def act_on_bar():
            ...

        func_dict = {'foo': act_on_foo,
                     'bar': act_on_bar}

        param = request.GET.get('param')
        func_dict[param]()
```

Perhaps an even better design would be to move the `act_on_foo` and `act_on_bar` functions to another module to decouple the view from the logic behind it.

And some nitpicking: 
Try to avoid mixing `"` and `'` in the same piece of code. Pick one and stick to it.

Comment: ahh I know about the " and ' it is bothering me too. I switched some time back to " and I didn't want to go through the code and change everything